# Reading multiple xl files into dataframe

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

I have been using `XLConnect` function `loadworkbook` to load each xlsx file into R then `rbind` to merge them together. what is the best way of doing this instead of writing multiple df to later merge them. I am trying to use the code below to merge my excel files into 2 dataframes(2 sheet names for most files). The columns are always the same but the file names will change.

> Current /slow way

```
require(XLConnect)
df <- loadWorkbook(paste(location,'UK.xlsx',sep=""))
dfb <- loadWorkbook(paste(location,'US.xlsx',sep=""))
UK <-readWorksheet(df,sheet="School",startRow=0,startCol=0,autofitRow=TRUE,endCol=21,header=TRUE)
US <-readWorksheet(dfb,sheet="School",startRow=0,startCol=0,autofitRow=TRUE,endCol=21,header=TRUE)
School  <-  rbind(UK,US)
UK <-readWorksheet(df,sheet="College",startRow=0,startCol=0,autofitRow=TRUE,endCol=21,header=TRUE)
US <-readWorksheet(dfb,sheet="College",startRow=0,startCol=0,autofitRow=TRUE,endCol=21,header=TRUE)
College  <- rbind(UK,US)
```

> New code

`require(readxl)
filelist<- list.files(location,pattern='xlsx',full.names = T)`
How can I read each sheetname into a dataframe when not every file has both sheetnames. I need 2 dataframes 1 for School and 1 for College.
I think I need to try something like `Schools <-lapply(filelist, read_excel, sheet="School")` but I get Error: Sheet 'School' not found. I think this error is because sheet School is not on every file. I am using `list.files` because the filenames are not always the same.

Comment: You should read through the available functions in the package to see if there is one that will provide the names of the worksheets as a vector. If yes, then you can check for the presence of the sheets. For example, the `openxlsx` package has a function `getSheetNames` for such a purpose.

Comment: The sheetnames are always the same School and College but not every file has both and thats why I dont know how to merge them together.

Comment: I need a dataframe that will merge every sheetname called School for every file and do the same for College but I dont know what the best way of doing this. Thanks

Comment: You could try to grab the sheet School, and catch an error if it fails and then just gracefully move on. You can use `tryCatch` to do that.

Answer (score 1):

What about this approach?

```
library(purrr)
library(readxl)
# filenames to xl-sheets
files <- sprintf("Mappe%i.xlsx", 1:3)

# read only df for xl-files with school-sheet
xl_school <- map_if(files, ~ "School" %in% excel_sheets(.x), ~read_excel(.x))
# read only df for xl-files with college-sheet
xl_college <- map_if(files, ~ "College" %in% excel_sheets(.x), ~read_excel(.x))

# combine school-files to data frame (repeat same for college)
school_df <- map_df(xl_school, function(x) if(is.data.frame(x)) x)

school_df
#> # A tibble: 3 × 1
#>      Test
#>     <chr>
#> 1    fdsf
#> 2  543534
#> 3 gfdgfdd
```

You might need to force the column type to be text. Just add `col_types = "text"` to the `read_excel()`-call:

```
# read only df for xl-files with school-sheet
xl_school <- map_if(files, ~ "School" %in% excel_sheets(.x), ~read_excel(.x, col_types = "text"))
# read only df for xl-files with college-sheet
xl_college <- map_if(files, ~ "College" %in% excel_sheets(.x), ~read_excel(.x, col_types = "text"))
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Glad I could help. But... Purrr? The package is names [purrr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=purrr), and CRAN / R is case sensitive.

Comment: This is now working but now on my College sheet it is returned the same results, I just tested this on some old data and I get the following error expecting numeric: which is related to a text col.

Comment: So it might be that sometimes (i.e. in some fumes) columns *only* contain numeric values, and sometimes text? If so, you could convert to character before calling map_df: `xl_school <- map(xl_school, ~as.character(.x))` - I can't check yet because I'm writing from my mobile.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I wont b able to convert to character before map_df because I am getting the error from map_if. using your second option is I currently have `xl_school <- map_if(files, ~ "School" %in% excel_sheets(.x), col_types = "text",~read_excel(.x))` bit I get  unused argument (col_types = "text")

Comment: if I try `xl_school <- map_if(files, ~ "School" %in% excel_sheets(.x), ~read_excel(col_types = "text",.x))` I get Error: Need one name and type for each column

Comment: I have updated the example, does it work for you? Else, you need to provide a reproducible example to better understand what's going on...

Comment: I have updated R using your example but I am still getting Error: Need one name and type for each column.`xl_school <- map_if(files, ~ "School" %in% excel_sheets(.x), read_excel(.x, col_types = "text"))` please see XL dummy data to use. Headers 'ID,Name,Expiry Dt,Office,Period,Prem,Limit,Order,Written,Comments,Field Checked,Error Y/N,Field Errors' most data is text. columns from Period to Field Errors can be blank so I think this could be the cause?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144054/discussion-between-new2programming-and-daniel).